# Android HandlerThread in singleton

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, sdk

I am writing an SDK that allows a user of the SDK to request data and have it returned to them asynchronously.

To access the SDK I decided to use a Singleton pattern. I do this because they may want to use the SDK from several different activities or fragments and I want each component that uses it to have the same instance. So the user will call MyClass.getInstance() which will return an instance of MyClass to them. Then they can call myClass.doAsynchronousOp(), etc...

One issues I am having is that when a user calls a method on the SDK it will do a bunch of work and I don't want to block the caller's thread. So, the solution I came up with was to create an instance of a HandlerThread when the class is first instantiated. Then when the user calls a method on the singleton class that is supposed to be asynchronous I create a Runnable and run it using the HandlerThread. This seems to work pretty well, but I have a few questions:

1) Let's say the user gets an instance of my singleton and calls one of the asynchronous methods. Now the class is holding a running HandlerThread. When the activity is destroyed is it imperative that I call .quit() on my HandlerThread? If so, I pretty much need to make the user call a method like myClass.unregister() in the onDestroy() method of they're activity which is ok, but I'd rather be able to do it automatically for them. Is it bad practice to not call .quit() on my HandlerThread when the application component holding it gets destroyed?

2) Since this is a singleton I'm noticing that even if the Activity that is holding it is destroyed, the instance can remain in memory. So if the Activity is destroyed and then recreated (device rotation) then my constructor of the singleton doesn't get run again. This is problematic because I setup my HandlerThread in the constructor. If I call .quit() on the HandlerThread when the Activity gets destroyed and then the activity gets recreated, the HandlerThread still exists in the singleton object, but now it's in the Terminated state and I can't use it. Is there a good way around this?

Maybe a more general question: How can I provide asynchronous access to my SDK without running into thread lifecycle vs. android component lifecycle issues?

Comment: have you heard about `Service`s?

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought of attempting this using a Service. I'm actually using the public facing singleton that I describe above to control a started service that can run while the parent application is in the foreground or background. However, having a Service running just to serve async calls to my public facing class seems like overkill. Do you have any examples of projects where this is done?